# Absense of targetNamespace causing exceptions to schema

Tags: xsd, schema

I'm trying to understand why the absence of a targetNamespace causes the following errors in my sample XML schema.  If I remove the targetNamespace (**targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd"**), I get the following errors:

> Namespace 'http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd' is not
>   available to be referenced in this
>   schema.  XMLSchema1.xsd   30
>
> The 'http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd:ChildNamePK' identity
>   constraint is not declared.   XMLSchema1.xsd  30

If I add the targetNamespace back in, these errors go away but this is actually a sample from a sql annotated schema that I've shortened up for the purposes of this post.  Since all the elements are local, I wanted to remove the targetNamespace in my real schema. How would I correct the schema without having to add a targetNamespace?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="XMLSchema1"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Parent">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Child" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="OldestChild">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:key name="ChildNamePK">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//Child" />
      <xs:field xpath="Name" />
    </xs:key>
    <xs:keyref name="OldestChildFK" refer="ChildNamePK">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//OldestChild" />
      <xs:field xpath="Name" />
    </xs:keyref>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is the line:

```xml
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd"
```

This line says that any QNames that do not have a namespace prefix should be treated as if the namespace were `http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd`. This is called the default namespace.

The `refer` attribute in the `xs:keyref` element is one of these QNames, and the value you have set it to is `ChildNamePK` which does not have a namespace prefix. Since there is no namespace prefix, and since you have defined a default namespace, XML schema effectively treats this as if it were

```
refer="{http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd}ChildNamePK"
```

i.e. as if it referenced a ChildNamePK element in the `http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd` namespace.

However, by removing the `targetNamespace`, you are saying the your elements, including the ChildNamePK key, are not in a namespace. So the thing that the `refer` attribute references doesn't actual exist. This is what the second error is trying to tell you--it's looking for `http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd:ChildNamePK'` but it doesn't exist.

The right solution here is probably to just remove the `xmlns="..."` line so that there is no default namespace. That way the refer attribute will reference an a QName that is not in a namespace, which is exactly what ChildNamePK is when you remove the targetNamespace line.